# Axios get request how to cancel the request

Tags: react-hooks, axios, request

I am working on creating a hook that makes an API request to fetch statistics. However, when you navigate through the months, it hasn't yet retrieved the data from the previous request, and it starts fetching the next one, causing the statistics to jump as it keeps refreshing. I have added the cancelToken in the hook, but without success.

I hope someone can help me out and tell me what i'm missing.

**Code for the hook:**

---

```
import { atom, useAtom } from "jotai";
import axios from "axios";
import queryString from "query-string";

// Types
// import { MonthData, RevenueFunnelTypes, TotalsData } from "../../lib/types";
import {
  Revenue,
  RevenueQ,
  RevenueFunnelTypes,
  TotalCardsTypes,
} from "../../lib/types";

export type Status = "idle" | "loading";
export type Values = {
  revenueFunnel: RevenueFunnelTypes;
  totals: TotalCardsTypes;
  revenue: Revenue | null;
  revenueQ: RevenueQ | null;
  // month: MonthData[];
};

export const rowsStatusAtom = atom<Status>("idle");

type ApiRowsResponse = {
  body: any;
};

type State = {
  values: Values;
  status: Status;
  actions: {
    get: (
      type: "revenue" | "revenue-quarters" | "revenue-funnel" | "totals",
      date?: string
    ) => Promise<State["values"]>;
  };
};

export interface sortRowsProps {
  id: number;
  order: number;
}

// Services
const createApiUrl = (route?: string, params?: any) => {
  return queryString.stringify({
    path: route,
    ...params,
  });
};

export default function useStats(): State {
  const [values, setValues] = useAtom(valuesAtom);
  const [status, setStatus] = useAtom(rowsStatusAtom);

  const CancelToken = axios.CancelToken;
  const source = CancelToken.source();

  const getCurrentValues = async function (
    type: "revenue" | "revenue-quarters" | "revenue-funnel" | "totals",
    date?: string
  ): Promise<ApiRowsResponse | any> {

    const url = createApiUrl("statistics", {
      type: type,
      date,
    });

    return axios
      .get(`?${url}`, {
        cancelToken: source.token
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        return response.data;
      })
      .catch(function (thrown) {
        if (axios.isCancel(thrown)) {
          console.log('Request canceled', thrown.message);
        } else {
          // handle error
        }
      })
  };

  // Actions
  // Get the current rows from the server
  const get = async (
    type: "revenue" | "revenue-quarters" | "revenue-funnel" | "totals",
    date?: string
  ): Promise<State["values"]> => {
    setStatus("loading");

    const data = await getCurrentValues(type, date);

    if (type === "revenue-funnel") {
      setValues((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        revenueFunnel: data.body,
      }));
    } else if (type === "revenue") {
      setValues((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        revenue: data.body,
      }));
    } else if (type === "revenue-quarters") {
      setValues((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        revenueQ: data.body,
      }));
    } else if (type === "totals") {
      setValues((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        totals: data.body,
      }));
    }

    setStatus("idle");

    return data.body;
  };

  return {
    values,
    status,
    actions: {
      get,
    },
  };
}
```

---

**Below is the function that handles navigation:**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (loading && state === 0) {
      actions.get("totals").then(() => {
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [loading, state]);


  // Functions
  const goToNextMonth = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const updatedDate = moment(selectedDate).add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    setSelectedDate(updatedDate);
    actions.get("totals", updatedDate).then(() => setLoading(false));
  };

  const goToPreviousMonth = () => {
    setLoading(true);
    const updatedDate = moment(selectedDate).subtract(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    setSelectedDate(updatedDate);
    actions.get("totals", updatedDate).then(() => setLoading(false));
  };
```

Created an Sandbox as demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/axioscancelrequest-jdstpz?file=/src/App.tsx

Disable cache and throttling so low as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never cancel the previous request. Start each request by disabling the previous (if exists), generate a new token source, and save it on a `ref` (`tokenSource`), so the next request can cancel it:

```
export default function useStats(): State {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useAtom(valuesAtom);
  const [status, setStatus] = useAtom(rowsStatusAtom);
  const tokenSource = useRef<null | CancelTokenSource>(null);

  const getCurrentMovies = async function (): Promise<ApiRowsResponse | any> {
    tokenSource.current?.cancel('Operation canceled by the user.');

    const source = axios.CancelToken.source();

    tokenSource.current = source;

    const returnData = axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
        cancelToken: source.token
      })
```

However, `CancelToken` is deprecated, and you should use the standard `AbortController`:

```
export default function useStats(): State {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useAtom(valuesAtom);
  const [status, setStatus] = useAtom(rowsStatusAtom);
  const controllerRef = useRef<null | AbortController>(null);

  const getCurrentMovies = async function (): Promise<ApiRowsResponse | any> {
    controllerRef.current?.abort("Operation canceled by the user.");

    const controller = new AbortController();

    controllerRef.current = controller;

    const returnData = axios
      .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts", {
        signal: controller.signal
      })
```

Comment: That make senses thanks updated my sandbox, but without success.. < https://codesandbox.io/s/axioscancelrequest-jdstpz?file=/src/hooks/useStats.tsx >

Comment: If the responses are quick enough, you're unable to cancel them. Use throttle to slow 35 in devtools network tab.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the loading state you can conditionally stop the user to call the next request

```
const goToNextMonth = () => {
  if(!loading){
  setLoading(true);
  const updatedDate = moment(selectedDate).add(1, 'month').format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  setSelectedDate(updatedDate);
  actions.get("totals", updatedDate).then(() => setLoading(false));}
};
```

Comment: This works, but it's not what I want because now you need to wait until the last request is loaded. Visitors may skip to the next month instead of waiting for the data of the next month to load.